# Pandas query could not convert to a valid Python identifier?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One issue may be that python is not reading my back tick but instead treating it like a blank space:

```
'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_PAY__LPAR_£M_SLASH_m_RPAR_'
                                                 ^
"`PAY (£M/m)` < '3'"
            ^
```

I'm searching a CSV file with spaces within the columns (cannot change this naming decision).

I also need to use query as it's a dynamic query that changes depending on inputs. (I haven't included this code as I am just trying to get it to work manually)

I've tried this without '3' and nothing changed.

I'm performing a query with the following code:

```
data = df.query("`PAY (£M/m)` < '3'")
```

`SyntaxError: Could not convert 'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_PAY__LPAR_£M_SLASH_m_RPAR_' to a valid Python identifier.`

Weirdly in the above error we have `__` between the left parenthesis and the word PAY although below is the consoles output + the code written manually into the query.

Below is my CSV file exported and copied from a txt:

```
PAY (£M/m)  INITIALS   ID
         2        ZE  223
         5        NY  532
         1        MA  122
         3        ON  873
         3        LS  235
```

Comment: Is there an issue with doing `df = df[df['PAY (£M/m)'] < 3]`?

Comment: @TYZ I want to keep df as it's used multiple times, it is also a dynamic search query which can change (I didn't include this code as it's working and not relevant).

Comment: @user19077881 "PAY (£M/m) < '3'" - this is a raw paste from my query

Comment: @user19077881 from the Pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html — 'You can refer to column names that are not valid Python variable names by surrounding them in backticks. Thus, column names containing spaces or punctuations (besides underscores) or starting with digits must be surrounded by backticks. (For example, a column named “Area (cm^2)” would be referenced as `Area (cm^2)`). '. To add to this here is snippet of another query I've written in a different program: f = f"`P ID` == '{id}'"

Comment: @OttoLuck you can simply rename the df that's assigned to after filter: `data = df[df['PAY (£M/m)'] < 3]` and if you want to completely separate the objects, you can add `.copy()`.

Comment: @TYZ here is an earlier snippet of my code f = ' & '.join(filterArr), the user may be applying 1-5 different/random combinations of filters. This is why I needed to use query.

Comment: It's the pound sign that's causing the problem (`£`). I'm surprised no one else mentioned that. Have you considered replacing it with something like `GBP`? The column could then be `PAY (GBP M/m)`. That's the ISO 4217 code for it, btw.

Comment: @wjandrea I cannot change anything in the CSV file unfortunately. Initially it wasn't running at all until I added unicode escape:  df = pd.read_csv("Pay_file.csv", encoding='unicode_escape').

Comment: @OttoLuck I meant changing the dataframe, not the CSV.

Comment: @wjandrea this fixed the issue and it currently works, for future reference is there really no work around to keep the £ in the dataframe? I'd really prefer it although if there isn't any fix that's no problem.

Comment: @user19077881 This is what I thought too, when I print the entire dataframe it outputs the £ sign fine.

Comment: @user19077881 That's not the issue. The error happens when trying to do a `.query()` on that column name.

Comment: @OttoLuck It's in the docs you linked: *"For other characters that fall outside the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F) and those that are not further specified in PEP 3131, the query parser will raise an error."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the £ sign. I replaced it with

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('£', 'GBP')
```

and changed the query to suit this new change and the error was fixed.

From the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

> During parsing a number of disallowed characters inside the backtick quoted string are replaced by strings that are allowed as a Python identifier. These characters include all operators in Python, the space character, the question mark, the exclamation mark, the dollar sign, and the euro sign. For other characters that fall outside the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F) and those that are not further specified in PEP 3131, the query parser will raise an error.